# Ways to check why my cursor execute is so slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a script using psycopg2 several times. Since around a week's time, it executes my queries terribly slow in one part of the code, whereas in other it performs as usuall. This did not happen before - I have been running this code many times before with no such problem.

I am trying to undersatnd why in this particular case, execution is so slow (around 2 seconds) and what can I do to check it more thouroughly?

-Win10
-Python 3.7.4
-Psycopg2 2.8.3
->All run via PyCharm
-PostgreSQL 9.2

What I tried:
-Running same querty in pgAdmin -> works fine and fast
-Connection ->switched from Wi-Fi to LAN, no result
-Checked code for actual moments when the code becomes slow -> slows down on execute statement.
-Checked the web, but found only problems related to fetchall() under search crtiteria involvin slowness and psycopg.
-Checked win10 updates if these do not cause some problems but it seems that's not the case -> code runs fine in other parts of the script.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=adres, port=port, database="database", user=log, password=pas)

cur = conn.cursor()
query = """SELECT string_agg(pn.full_name,','), 
string_agg(ms.wrong_fullname,',')      
FROM names as pn
LEFT JOIN name_misspellings as ms on (ms.id_person_name = pn.id)
WHERE pn.id_human = 9220478"""
cur.execute(query)
#this bit takes longer
row = cur.fetchone()
cur.close()
```

Comment: The slowness is related to the query that you failed to show. You should show the actual query, and say if concurency can be involved (other instances of the script, multi-threading, or other accesses to the same database)

Comment: added example to the above code - it takes ~16msc on db. No multithreading involved, no other instances of the same script, no other accesses to the same db in the same time in the script (cur.close() in each case - I assume that does the job?) The db itself is production db and no changes were made, no problems with performance noted.

Comment: The only reason I can imagine for the query being slower at one point and not in others is memory resource contention.The Python interpretor and/or the postgres process use a lot of memory and at that point an important garbage collecting is required or (even worse) you start swapping. Anyway, with proper indexes, the query should not require a lot of resources. Do you have indexes on names(id_human) and name_misspellings(id_person_name)?

Comment: db has indexes, and on the same maching via pgAdmin i see no problems in perfomance (it takes 16msc for that query). What is even more interesting, couple lines above the code, I have similiar ask to the same db and it executes fast. I checked memory current usage on my side and its ok - around 50mb ram for python and 400mb for pyCharm, which should be ok. I checked pgAdmin server status and my query is in green, it shows no lock problems etc, its just slow to execute (same process id for couple seconds). There are no restrictions for user I use to connect to db.

Comment: Then I won't be able to help because I can imagine no hint. Sorry and good luck...